# How to return the first lines of multiple files?

Tags: python

I have a csv that contains the names of the samples at the first line of the file which I would like to return to a list in order to rename the experimental data that comes later. The file essentially looks like this for the first two lines:

```
Solvent, , Sample, ,
Wavelength, Absorbance, Wavelength, Absorbance
x data, y data, x data, y data
```

and I would like to rename the two absorbance columns to "Solvent" and "Sample."

I've written this to get a list of the first lines in the files:

```
def AbsColNames(pathname):
     for file in glob.glob(raw_UV + "*/*.csv"):
         with open(file) as f:
             names = f.readline()
             return names
```

However, it does not loop through the list of files and instead only gives me the first line of the first file. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: "However, it does not loop through the list of files and instead only gives me the first line of the first file." The code you posted here will give the first line of the **last** file. Are you sure the code you posted is the same as the code you are actually running. If not, please [edit] your question here. Pay especially close attention that the indentation here matches the indentation in your code.

Comment: You're right, I had been screwing around with the indentation and noticed that. Edited to give the code that reads through only the first file.

Comment: @adamzr There is no point putting an unconditional return in a loop - it will return on the first iteration and that will be the end. What you need to do is append to a list inside the loop and then afterwards (outside the loop) return the list. (Initialise the empty list before the loop.)

Comment: @alaniwi Thank you, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @adamzr Just for your information, you can instead put `yield` inside the loop (instead of `return`) and then in the calling code you can do for example `for line in AbsColNames():` to loop over the first lines. However, although the code would look rather similar, it is doing something significantly different under the hood and it is really a more advanced topic (look up generators if you are interested). For now, you are best just using a list as I've described - and Caliuf's answer implements - but it's a topic you can revisit later, especially if memory usage becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration you are overwriting `names` value.

You need probably something like:

```
def AbsColNames(pathname):
     names_list = []
     for file in glob.glob(raw_UV + "*/*.csv"):
         with open(file) as f:
             names_list.append(f.readline())
     return names_list
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('folderPath') if isfile(join('folderPath', f))]

for file in onlyfiles:
    with open(join('folderPath', file), 'r') as f:
        first_line = f.readline()
        print first_line
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to building a list in memory:

```
def AbsColNames(pathname):
     for file in glob.glob(raw_UV + "*/*.csv"):
         with open(file) as f:
             yield f.readline()
```

This uses a generator to produce each initial line of each file. The caller can use this generator in a for loop just like a list, but without the memory overhead of a list.